# Storing profile information for asp.net users in separate columns instead of 1 long column?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

When you create profile information for an asp.net user, it creates all the property values in 1 field.  This is not the easiest thing to query.  Is there a way to tell it to store the values in separate columns like Address, City, State, Zipcode instead of a column called PropertyStringValues where the value might be something like City:s:0:10State:s:10:15.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to use a custom profile provider. [This one](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples/), created by Microsoft employee Hao Kung should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I actually saw that link before. I was curious if there was just a setting for it or if you had to implement a custom membership provider.  Thanks.